# Use JavaScript to fake click an anchor based on location.hash - WordPress, FAQ Plug-in

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom-events

This is a JavaScript question, but for use in a WordPress site/plug-in. I have installed a FAQ Plugin that expands and collapses the 'answer' when you click on the question, which is an h3 with an anchor. All of the FAQs are displayed on a single page.

Ultimately what I want to achieve is to create a link for, let's say 'Question Ten', on the home page, which will take the visitor to directly to 'Question Ten' on the FAQ page and expand the answer.

So far, I've been able to tweak the FAQ code to include an id on the anchor tag, using:

```
id="' . basename(get_permalink()) . '"
```

If the URL for that specific question is mysite.com/faq/this-is-question-ten, then the resulting id for the anchor would be "this-is-question-ten."

From there, on the homepage I have made the href for the link = mysite.com/faq-page#this-is-question-ten.

In the faq-page (template), in , I have declared a variable:

var anchorName = location.hash;
I have added an alert(anchorName), and the result is #this-is-question-ten.

From there I have tried to call:

```
$('#this-is-question-ten').click();
```

and/or

```
$('#this-is-question-ten').trigger('click');
```

whereby the function looks for an anchor with id = "#this-is-question-ten", and fake "clicks" the anchor. However, it is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well the javascript runs on ONE page and the FAQ are on another?
Than you cannot parse the variable from the first script to the second, not without modifying the URL.

IF you modify the URL you could also just build links like that

```
http://www.example.com/faq.php#this-is-question-ten
```

the browser will do the rest.

To expand the given anchor-node don't try to emulate a click, just call the expand function (based on the plugin you use you need to find the correct call for that)

so for example

```
$("#question-10").expand();
//or
$("#question-10").show();
//or
$("#question-10").toggle();
```

keep in mind: #question-10 is NOT the "button" or object to click, but the hidden container the answer hides in ;)

example:

```
<div class="faq">
    <a id="question-10" onclick="answer.expand('answer-10');"> This is the question </a>

    <div id="answer-10" style="display:none">
     THIS IS THE HIDDEN ANSWER
    </div>
</div>
```

Say you have a layout similar to the one above...
instead of trying to emulate a click on the question

```
$("question-10").click();
```

you should rather call the underlaying function directly:

```
if(anchorName == "question-10")
{
     answer.expand('answer-10');
}
```

Comment: Hi there ... if you see above I did modify:

Comment: @Tathiana so far so good, .. still: do not emulate a click if you can toggle the view with a function.. just take a look inside the extension code and you'll find the proper function to toggle the Answers, then use that on the hidden container you want to show, based on your anchor-name.. I'll add a short example above in a few

Comment: Hey @itsid, thanks so much for the response! Going to try but need some clarifications: 1) in my example I use anchor id = "this-is-question-ten", however in your example you use "question-10" - just want to make sure that you simply are using a different ID for you example and not missing something, and 2) you say "keep in mind: #question-10 is NOT the "button" or object to click, but the hidden container the answer hides in ...", however in your example you have "question-10" as id for the anchor tag and "answer-10" as the id for the div holding the hidden answer. Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: ok I think I understand, what was confusing me is that in the first part of your response you are using #question-10 as the answer, and in the second part of your response you are using #question-10 as the question (anchor).  I am going to give it a try.

Comment: yes. sorry about that, It'd been more obvious to use "answer" directly there. But I guess you know what to look for now.